# C++0x initializer list passed by reference

Tags: c++, c++11

I have tried to use C++0x initializer list as argument to a constructor call in this way:

```
Foo<float> foo("Foo 1", std::vector<const char *>({ "foo A", "foo B" }) );
```

with the constructor

```
Foo(const char *name, std::vector<const char *> &foos)
```

With this constructor the compiler complained:

```
error: no matching function for call to Foo<float>::Foo(
    const char [5], std::vector<const char *, std::allocator<const char *> >)
note: candidates are: Foo<T>::Foo(const char *, std::vector<const char *,
    std::allocator<const char *> >&) [with T = float]
```

However, when I've changed the constructor to

```
Foo(const char *name, std::vector<const char *> foos)
```

Everything worked as expected. Why does the first constructor not work? I thought the vector could be constructed in the place of constructor call and passed down by reference, but obviously there's some problem. Could anybody explain that?

Thanks

Btw. I am using g++ version 4.4.5

**EDIT:**
Thanks to the correct answers below, I have found also [why I can't do that](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1565600/how-come-a-non-const-reference-cannot-bind-to-a-temporary-object).

Comment: Have you tried a const reference?

Comment: Why are you saying `std::vector<const char *>({ "foo A", "foo B" })` ? That's needlessly introducing another temporary using the move constructor that the compiler has to elide. Better say `std::vector<const char *>{ "foo A", "foo B" }`. Of course you can just say `Foo<float> foo{"Foo 1", {"foo A", "foo B"}}`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You cannot bind a temporary to a `T&`.

You *can* bind a temporary to `T const&`:

```
Foo(const char* name, std::vector<const char*> const& foos)
```

But I'd question the sanity of a `vector` of `char` pointers. What's wrong with `std::string`?

Comment: Says about everything that has gone wrong here. Could you also not just pass the brace initializer list without the explicit call to the `vector` constructor?

Comment: You're right, when I used const std::vector<> &, I can pass the brace initializer list itself.
I am not using std::string, because the strings mostly get passed to C API underneath as they are - no concatenating and such.

Comment: Flavius: well, that's really no reason not to use `std::string`. It's safer (not ugly pointers all over the place) and `std::string::c_str()` only returns the address of the beginning of the internal data array (in all modern implementations, this is mandated by the C++11 Standard), which is instantaneous.

Comment: @Flavius: rubenvb is right. Needing to pass a char buffer to underlying C APIs is absolutely _not_ a reason to avoid `std::string`. (What you said would be rather like storing an `int` as its individual, component bits in `bool`s, just because you never do a `+` operation.) The benefits are enormous.

Answer (score 4):

Temporary cannot be bound to non-const reference, so do this:

```
Foo(const char *name, const std::vector<const char *> &foos)
                    //^^^^ note this
```

Answer (score 2):

The initializer list is a red hering, I think. You are trying to bind a temporary to a non-const reference, which is illegal. Try using a const reference.

```
Foo(const char *name, std::vector<const char *> const& foos)
```

Answer (score 1):

`std::vector<const char *> &foos` is lvalue reference. You are trying to pass rvalue, this is wrong. You can use either rvalue reference `std::vector<const char *> &&foos` or const reference `const std::vector<const char *> &foos`

Answer (score 0):

You cannot bind an rvalue `std::vector` to a non-const lvalue reference. You must take a const lvalue reference or an rvalue reference.

Answer (score 0):

You already have your answer, but since you have "initializer list" in the title, you may want to consider writing a (C++0x) initializer-list constructor, e.g. like so:

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(const char* name, std::initalizer_list<const char*> il)
      : name(name), buf(il)
    { }
private:
    const char * const name;
    std::vector<const char *> buf;
};
```

Then you're no longer an aggregate, but you can construct it like so:

```
Foo x("Name", { "ab", "cd", "ef" });
```

You even pass `il` as const-reference if you prefer.